# Where does "acutilobate" originate from?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, dictionaries, biology

I see the claim that *acutilobate* is a “dictionary-only” word, for example seen in the 1913 *Webster’s* dictionary. How would a word get into a dictionary that only appears in dictionaries and is not really a word in use? Once a word is in a dictionary such as *Webster’s* doesn’t that confer it life and wouldn’t it generally begin to enter the language in actual use? Websters defines it as a botany term: “Having acute lobes, as some leaves”. Where did *acutilobate* originate from as a word?

Comment: I don't know about that particular word, but lots of technical words are created anew. Anyway, a word usually gets into a dictionary because it is used, not the other way (a word appears in a dictionary so it starts to be used). Life is in the using. Many (comprehensive) dictionaries have the qualifiers 'obsolete', 'archaic', or 'rare' to show that they maybe once were used often but are not any more.

Comment: To the two close voters: This is primarily an etymology question of a valid word. I don't see how that is "too localised".

Comment: On your second (and third) sentences): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzxjoanw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Acutilobate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acutilobate):

> **Latin acutus (“sharp”) + lobe**
>
> (botany) Having acute lobes, as some leaves.

The word very likely comes from the Latin [acutilobus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acutilobus#Latin):

> Having pointed stems
>
> Used almost exclusively as a **taxonomic epithet**.

Searching for "[acutilobus](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=acutilobus%20&title=Special%3aSearch)" in Wikipedia yields:

> - [Orectochilus Acutilobus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orectochilus), a beetle
> - [Amaranthus acutilobus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth), a species of amaranth
> - [Myxopappus acutilobus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myxopappus), a member of the daisy family
> - [Ranunculus acutilobus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ranunculus_species), some sort of buttercup

As an adjective, acutilobate could well have been/still be used to describe such plants. Or perhaps it has since been superseded by some other term which has attracted the fancy of botanists worldwide. In any case, that does not mean that the word should no longer be in the dictionary. Some words survive. Some don't. This one very likely didn't, unlike its second cousin twice removed, [acutilingual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acutilingual)—meaning "*having a sharply pointed tongue or mouth, as certain bees*"—[which](http://www.alibaba.com/countrysearch/CN/acutilingual-bottle.html) has [found](http://www.dinodirect.com/wholesale-mask-venice-acutilingual-half-face-ball-halloween-masquerade.html) a [curious niche](http://www.ebay.com/itm/11x15mm-acutilingual-shape-black-freshwater-cultured-pearl-beads-strand-15-/120951930245) to survive in.

Comment: OED labels it "rare" and "obsolete"...

Comment: @GEdgar Is the etymology identical to the one stated above?

Comment: OED just says *[compare post-classical Latin acutilobatus (1841 or earlier)]*